# Euler-Fermat with double exponent

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to calculate $c$ from the following:

$31^{(41^{59})}$ ≡ $c \bmod 25$ with the help of Euler-Fermat.

I know how to calculate if there is only one exponent, but I am confused how to apply Euler-Fermat with this double exponent.

Could somebody give me a hint, please?

Thanks!

Comment: first calculate $41^{59}\bmod20$

Comment: As @J.W.Tanner says, $41^{59} \bmod \phi(25) = 41^{59} \bmod 20 = 1^{59} = 1$ as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

From Euler's theorem, $31^c\equiv31^{c \bmod20}\bmod25$, so first calculate $41^{59}\bmod20$.

You can also apply $a^b\equiv (a\bmod m)^b\bmod m$.

Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$(1+30)^n\equiv1+\binom n130^1\pmod{25}$$

Now $$a^{b^c}\equiv a^{b^c\pmod{\phi(m)}}\pmod m$$ for $(a,m)=1$

Finally $$41^{59}=(1+40)^{59}\equiv1\pmod{20}$$

Comment: Don't you want $59\cdot40\pmod{2\color{red}0}$, since it's in the exponent?

Comment: @Tanner, Thanks